# Error trying to install rinku gem on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-mavericks

I'm having trouble installing the rinku gem version '1.7.3' on Mavericks. I followed the advice of another post that suggested to install apple-gcc42 but that didn't help. I've also tried searching google and stack overflow but couldn't find this exact issue. Here is the error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...                          
ERROR:  Error installing rinku:                                                  
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.                             

    /Users/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb                  
creating Makefile                                                                

make  clean                                                                      

make                                                                             
compiling autolink.c                                                             
In file included from autolink.c:17:                                             
buffer.h:23:20: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory                       
In file included from autolink.c:17:                                             
buffer.h:41: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'uint8_t'           
In file included from autolink.c:18:                                             
autolink.h:31: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'uint8_t'       
autolink.h:31: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token                  
autolink.h:35: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'uint8_t'  
autolink.h:39: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'uint8_t'  
autolink.h:43: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'uint8_t'  
autolink.c:20:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory                     
autolink.c:21:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory                     
autolink.c:22:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory                      
autolink.c:23:19: error: ctype.h: No such file or directory                      
autolink.c:30: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'uint8_t'
```

... Had to leave out some of the error because it won't let me post this without a lower code to text ratio.

```
autolink.c: At top level:
autolink.c:256: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'uint8_t'
autolink.c: In function 'sd_autolink__url':
autolink.c:263: error: 'data' undeclared (first use in this function)
autolink.c:266: warning: implicit declaration of function 'isalpha'
autolink.c:269: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sd_autolink_issafe'
autolink.c:272: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strlen'
make: *** [autolink.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Comment: Got it to install by upgrading to ruby 2.0.0, still have no idea how to get it to work on 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

this ended up fixing it for 1.9.3

```
xcode-select --install
```